# How to Use Case When in a stored procedure to execute a different SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i got a problem of my homework~
i want execute different sql in proc to use CASE WHEN
and the code like this

```
CREATE  proc [dbo].[removeFileNew] (@transerid int,@Type int)  
as   
--PRINT @file
--PRINT @transerid


CASE  
    WHEN @Type=1 --report
    THEN 
        UPDATE order_report_path SET ReportPath=''
        WHERE tran_ser_id=@transerid

     WHEN @Type=2--gl

        UPDATE order_report_path SET GRpath=''
        WHERE tran_ser_id=@transerid

    WHEN @Type=3--ic
        UPDATE order_report_path SET ICpath=''
        WHERE tran_ser_id=@transerid

END
```

but it got some error like 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE''
How can i use the case when like use if in c++.
thx all..
Best Wishes.

Comment: You want to use `if` not `case`.  `case` is for a select/update/delete statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use CASE WHEN like this. In SQL this is meant to return a value, not control flow.

Use IF statements instead.

```
IF @Type=1 --report
BEGIN 
    UPDATE order_report_path SET ReportPath=''
    WHERE tran_ser_id=@transerid
END
ELSE IF @Type=2 --gl
BEGIN
    UPDATE order_report_path SET GRpath=''
    WHERE tran_ser_id=@transerid
END
ELSE IF @Type=3 --ic
BEGIN
    UPDATE order_report_path SET ICpath=''
    WHERE tran_ser_id=@transerid
END
```

Note that BEGIN / END statements are optional as long as you only have one instruction per block, but I still recommend that you keep them.

Same goes for ELSE: not THAT useful in this context but it would be if your expressions were more complex and/or if needs be that you must make sure only one block is executed.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF @Type = 1
  BEGIN
    UPDATE order_report_path
    SET    ReportPath = ''
    WHERE  tran_ser_id = @transerid
  END
ELSE IF @Type = 2
  BEGIN
    UPDATE order_report_path
    SET    GRpath = ''
    WHERE  tran_ser_id = @transerid
  END
ELSE IF @Type = 3
  BEGIN
    UPDATE order_report_path
    SET    ICpath = ''
    WHERE  tran_ser_id = @transerid
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a single query by putting the `case` inside the update:

```
    UPDATE order_report_path
        SET ReportPath = (case when @Type = 1 then '' else ReportPath end),
            GRpath = (case when @Type = 2 then '' else GRPath end),
            ICpath = (case when @Type = 3 then '' else ICpath end)
    WHERE tran_ser_id = @transerid
    AND @Type in (1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Bad idea. This will needlessly write into columns that aren't supposed to be written. Could be a problem if a trigger with UPDATE(field) function was in use.

Comment: @Crono1981 . . . What?  This query only affects the rows that need to be affected.  Databases don't write records or columns, they write pages (in general).  Do you understand how databases work?

Comment: I said that this will update into three COLUMNS when update on only ONE is needed. Database page writing is way out of scope here.

Comment: @Crono1981 . . . In memory transfers of small amounts of data are negligible compared to the actual work done by an `update`, in terms of locking the table/page/rows and logging the changes.  There is an incredibly small additional cost to updating another column in a row that is already being updated.  On the other hand, there might be a large advantage in keeping the code compact and in one place.

Comment: Read my comment again: my concern isn't on performance but on design. A potential trigger on order_report_path will see three fields being modified rather than one. That could be misleading. Therefore, IMHO, and as pretty and performant your code can be, this is not what you will want to teach to somebody who's learning TSQL.

Comment: @Crono1981 . . . It is actually a pretty common way of solving the problem that SQL in general and SQL Server in particular doesn't offer a way to *not* update a column.  A trigger should be robust enough to do what it is intended (so I would view this "problem" as an issue with the trigger, not the update code).  And to be honest, I've never fully understood `update(field)`, because the values of `inserted` and `deleted` can be compared directly.

Comment: What do you mean? If the column isn't part of the UPDATE statement then it will not be updated? As for the update function, it depends on what you want to do in the trigger. If for example you just want to make sure that a field cannot be updated regardless of permissions then you will want to use the update function rather than inserted and updated. These two aren't cheap.

Comment: @Crono1981 . . . Clearly the column *can* be updated.  It is being updated depending on the argument being compared.

Comment: I'm not following you here (sorry, english isn't my main language as you probably noticed by now :) ). If the column is never mentionned in the UPDATE statement then how exactly will it be updated depending on whatever argument comparison?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47790/discussion-between-gordon-linoff-and-crono1981)

Comment: @Crono1981: I have agree with Gordon: (except for the typo and missing condition, now fixed) this is a valid solution that doesn't deserve downvotes. Even a good one. Concerns about triggers are exotic side issues, hardly relevant for a user struggling with `CASE` statements.

Comment: I never said it wasn't working or that it didn't deserved votes. I said it's a bad idea to expose this as a solution to somebody who's still having homeworks to do. As "exotic" as you think triggers issues can be, that's still very good advice to give to someone learning the TSQL mechanics. So I stand by my point: it's necessary to learn how to code efficiently first. Especially in TSQL where code almost always ends up being messy anyway.

Comment: Besides, from my perspective, the OP was trying to recreate the switch(case) control flow pattern commonly found in other languages. To that the answer is *not* CASE WHEN.